# Gmail api scope & format mismatch

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I'm trying to write tiny gmail client for android as training. 
I took gmail api guide sample from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android modified it a little to get messages with headers & body by threads. I set scopes to `GmailScopes.Gmail_modify` and edited main request function as this:

```
private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
            // Get the labels in the user's account.
            String user = "me";
            List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
            ListLabelsResponse listResponse =
                    mService.users().labels().list(user).execute();
            ListThreadsResponse listThreads = null;
            try {
             listThreads = mService.users().threads().list(user).execute();
            } catch (IOException ioex){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "First: " + ioex.toString());
            }

            for (Thread thread : listThreads.getThreads()) {
                try {
                    thread = mService.users().threads().get(user, thread.getId()).setFormat("full").execute();
                } catch (IOException ioex){
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Second: " + ioex.toString());
                }
                for(Message message : thread.getMessages()){
                    labels.add(message.getId());
                }

            }
            return labels;
        }
```

But I always get

```
Second: GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden            {
                                                                             "code" : 403,
                                                                             "errors" : [ {
                                                                               "domain" : "global",
                                                                               "message" : "Metadata scope doesn't allow format FULL",
                                                                               "reason" : "forbidden"
                                                                             } ],
                                                                             "message" : "Metadata scope doesn't allow format FULL"
                                                                           }
```

I tried different scopes configurations but seems like service scope is always set to `GmailScopes.GMAIL_METADATA`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is exactly my problem these day when playing with Google APIs Explorer. And here is what I did to solve it:

1. Go to https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions
2. Choose the app you are playing with, mine is Google APIs Explorer
3. Click Remove > OK
4. Next time, just request exactly which permissions you need.

Hope it help :)

Comment: What are the exact permissions to check? I can't find a working combination.

Answer (score 7):

you should remove the "metadata" scope.

check app permissions to make sure you have only these 3 scopes:

1. https://mail.google.com/
2. gmail.modify
3. readonly
   , or else remove the permissions and add them again.

Comment: Still works in 2020, this should be the accepted answer.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After getting permissions to device Contacts you have to approve chosen copes. So first time I approved metadata scope. Next times when I needed to approve readonly scope, there was no window to do it. So you need to delete scopes permissions from google account and reinstall app.

Comment: Do you mean you delete your scopes from admin console and re-add them? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

got the same error when a service account which i was using had only these scopes ( [Security > API Controls > Domain-wide Delegation](https://admin.google.com/ac/owl/domainwidedelegation) ):

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata`

and addition of

- `https://mail.google.com/`

solved the issue