# Gmail API .NET: Get full message

Tags: gmail-api, service-accounts, getmessage

How do I get the full message and not just the metadata using gmail api?

I have a service account and I am able to retrieve a message but only in the metadata, raw and minimal formats. How do I retrieve the full message in the full format? The following code works fine

```
var request = service.Users.Messages.Get(userId, messageId);
request.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Metadata;
Message message = request.Execute();
```

However, when I omit the format (hence I use the default format which is FULL) or I change the format to `UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Full`
I get the error: `Metadata scope doesn't allow format FULL`

I have included the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify,
https://mail.google.com/
```

How do I get the full message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to remove the scope for the metadata to be able to get the full message format.

Comment: yeah - curious .. I had thought that the most permissive scope would override the lesser but this would appear to not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

The user from the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566099/gmail-api-scope-format-mismatch) have the same error.

Try this out first.

1. Go to [https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions)
2. Choose the app you are working with.
3. Click Remove > OK
4. Next time, just request exactly which permissions you need.

Another thing, try to use `gmailMessage.payload.parts[0].body.data`and to decode it into readable text, do the following from the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026099/how-to-get-full-message-body-in-gmail):

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;

System.out.println(StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(gmailMessage.payload.parts[0].body.data)));
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655874/cannot-get-the-body-of-email-with-gmail-php-api/32660892#32660892) for further reference.

Comment: I removed the app (The Google API explorer) and tried again, but same error. What does point 4 mean(Next time, just request exactly which permissions you need)? Am I supposed to edit my scopes? I am able to execute the request so I am not able to get to the gmailMessage.payload.parts[0].body.data

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    public String getMessage(string user_id, string message_id)
    {
         Message temp =service.Users.Messages.Get(user_id,message_id).Execute();
         var parts = temp.Payload.Parts;
         string s = "";
         foreach (var part in parts) {
                byte[] data = FromBase64ForUrlString(part.Body.Data);
                s += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
         }
        return s
       }

    public static byte[] FromBase64ForUrlString(string base64ForUrlInput)
        {
            int padChars = (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4) == 0 ? 0 : (4 - (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(base64ForUrlInput, base64ForUrlInput.Length + padChars);
            result.Append(String.Empty.PadRight(padChars, '='));
            result.Replace('-', '+');
            result.Replace('_', '/');
            return Convert.FromBase64String(result.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: I get the error "Metadata scope doesn't allow format FULL". Full is the default format so when I do not specify the format, I get this error.