# Google graph: get raw mail

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I'm trying to read google mail in raw format. Sometimes it working fine. Sometimes it getting an error like:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Metadata scope doesn't allow format
>   RAW [403] Errors [    Message[Metadata scope doesn't allow format RAW]
>   Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global] ]

My request is

```
var request = service.Users.Messages.Get("me", mailId);
request.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Raw;
var response = request.Execute();
```

It's also getting error for

```
request.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Full;
```

The scopes are

```
https://mail.google.com/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify  
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: This looks like it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593958. I'm not closing as a duplicate as it may well not be, but given that the error message explicitly talks about scopes, it would be good to include information about which scopes you're using in your question.

Comment: The link is useful for getting format full message but not for raw format

Comment: Now, getting same error for full

Comment: But you still haven't provided any information about what scopes you're using. This lack of information makes it hard to help you.

Comment: Now I update my question with using scopes

Comment: Hmm... that seems odd given the error message you're getting. Have you tried using *just* https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly as the scope, just as an experiment?

Comment: same error happened

Comment: Okay, I'll try to reproduce. Could you provide a [mcve] so we can see exactly what you're doing and reproduce the problem?

Comment: Finally, I it's working fine. no need to readonly scope. Just removing all history of browser and sign in newly. Then it's working. Thanks @JonSkeet