# Gmail API scope issue? Cannot get full message body

Tags: gmail-api

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/something%40gmail.com/messages/something?format=full&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Hello. I'd like to get the message body for the message with the above request.
During authentication, I checked every possible permission, yet I'm getting the following response:

`Metadata scope doesn't allow format FULL`

What am I missing here?

Comment: maybe this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566099/gmail-api-scope-format-mismatch) can help you with your problem.